# Extract X value from corresponding Y value from a List or Transpose

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a list of X values and Y values separately, and also together with:

```
data=Transpose[{X,Y}]
```

This data is from a chromatogram, and I want to extract the retention time tR (X) that corresponds to the highest value of absorbance (Y). I normally perform an interpolation with

```
f=Interpolation[data];
tR=x/.Last[FindMaximum[f[x],{x,1}]];
```

For some reason this approach is not working with a recent chromatogram, and I wanted to extract the X value that corresponds to the maximum Y value directly from the two lists like this:

```
Position[Y,Max[Y]]
```

This gives me the position in the vector where I can find the X value I want. If I input the value manually I get the X value I am looking for:

```
X[[9970]]
```

So far so good. However, if I try to assign Position[Y,Max[Y]] to a variable (for automation, since I have a program that does all the data extraction and plotting for me), I cannot get the X value:

```
ymaxposition=Position[Y,Max[Y]];
tR=X[[ymaxposition]]
```

> Part::pspec: Part specification {{9970}} is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>

This isn't working either:

```
Position[Y,Max[Y]]
tR=X[[%]]
```

Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: `X[[ymaxposition[[1,1]]]]`

Comment: What *Kuba* said. And I assume there will not be more than one maximum in `Y`? Else you'll want to be sure to handle that appropriately.

Comment: @Kuba. Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: `Position` provides the result in a format that is suitable for use with `Extract`. Braces are used to indicate the depth/level of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you pick the X value directly from data? something like this:

```
Sort[data, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &][[1, 1]]
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Also `X[[ymaxposition[[1,1]]]]` worked

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Y={1,3,4,1,2,3,5,5,2};
X=Y-1;
data=Transpose[{X,Y}];
Select[data,#[[2]]==Max[Y]&][[All, 1]]
```

or shorter

```
Pick[X, Y, Max[Y]]
```